# Does Weblogic support local configuration across multiple managed servers

Tags: weblogic11g, wlst

In Weblogic, Is there a way to ensure that every machine in the domain(with managed servers) has the local configuration files.

Comment: What do you mean by "local configuration files" ? If you are talking about domain's configuration files, each managed server gets its own configuration files from the admin server when it starts via a t3 or http connection ; therefor the server is sure to start with up to date configuration files.

Comment: What about the changes made via console, they get updated in th config.xml, which is the Adminserver machine. Is there a way to get these changes on all the manages servers which are in different data centres but in a single domain.

Comment: Context - 
Should domain_home be on shared storage. How managed servers running on different physical machines gain access to domain home. 

Machine 1 - Admin server with domain created on local stroage. 
Machine 2 - Managed servers part of domain. Managed servers created with Machine2 IP and Port using pack and unpack.

Comment: All changes you make to your domain via the admin console, via WLST or via any JMX or REST client are managed by your admin server and will be pushed to managed servers. Some changes can be applyed without a server restart, some will require your manage server to restart to be applied. Managed servers and the admin server exchange information via HTTP or T3 requests/responses.